# How do I identify my network interfaces?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, network-manager

I am trying to set up a virtual machine on Ubuntu 16.04 and need to define the 3 network interfaces.

I have used `hardinfo` and `ifconfig` and both tell me that instead of the usual `eth0`, `eth1` etc. the interface names are:

```
enp0s25

enp2s1f0

enp2s1f1
```

However, when I try to use these in the interfaces file and restart the network, it does not recognise these interface names.

From `journalctl -xe` I get lines such as:

```
Dec 29 10:32:10 Xerxes ifup[6531]: Unknown interface enp0s25
```

In addition, the interfaces are renames by virtualbox (my virtual machine) to em0 and em1 (the third is not recognised at all).

Can anyone help me understand what is going on please?

Answer (score 1):

Names like `enp0s3` are new. To get back traditional names like `eth0` run this command.

```
# ln -s /dev/null /etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-setup-link.rules
```

It's from [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration#Reverting_to_traditional_device_names), but I guess it should work in Ubuntu, too.

Comment: Thanks Jirka but before I try that I would like to understand why the interfaces file definitions are not being recognised.  It may be a bug that needs to be resolved.